# Filtering a dataframe based on numerical values in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter the rows in a dataframe based on the values of a column. If the numerical value is above 2, then it takes those rows, if it is below 2 it should not take those rows.
Sample dataframe

```
| Number | Machine Name | Number of jobs|

|:-------|:------------:| -------------:|

| One    | Power Drill  | 1             |
| Two    | Wench        | 3             |
|Three   | Screwdriver  | 9             |
```

Desired outcome: The code should look at the third column "Number of jobs" and see if the number is greater than 2 then it should take it, else it should ignore it.
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import glob
import os

source_folder = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\YYY'

file_names = glob.glob(os.path.join(source_folder, '*.xlsm'))

target_file = 'XXX.xlsm'

table_2 = pd.read_excel(target_file)

job_list = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
new_df = table_2['Number of jobs'].isin(job_list)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/PycharmProjects/Rig Visualisation/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Number of jobs'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\PycharmProjects\Rig Visualisation\main.py", line 57, in <module>
    new_df = table_2['Number of jobs'].isin(job_list)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Number of jobs'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Edit: Upon further investigation I discovered the following:

```
  Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3
0           NaN     Number   Machine Name       Jobs
1           NaN          1      Power Drill    1
2           NaN          2      Wench          4
3           NaN          3      Screwdriver    5
```

It seems that pandas is not reading the column names, but rather it is reading them as unnamed, why is that?

Comment: As stated in the error message, this is not a filtering issue: it seems there is no 'Number of jobs' column in your dataframe. Check your column name: it might be spelled differently, there might be a trailing space in the name...

Comment: That's what I thought at first,I double checked and even named the column with one word but I got the same error.

Comment: if your headers in the excel sheet aren't the top row you'll need to adjust using `pd.read_excel(target_file, header={put row number -1 here}). https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html